# How do I remove Django HTML as an option in the VSCode Select Language Mode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode is still very new to me. Every time I open ah HTML document from my class assignments (or any ordinary HTML document for that matter) VSCode defaults to "Django HTML" over regular "HTML" formatting.

I'd like to remove Django HTML as the default so that any time I open up a .html document the default formatting is regular HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First type CRTL + K, then press M

Click "Configure File Association '.html'..."

Type "HTML" into the search bar

Select "`<HTML>`"

If you do the same first 3 steps again, you should now see "`<HTML>` *Current Default*" which confirms that you have done these steps correctly.

Comment: This is not the actual solution. Because even after closing the file and opening it again, VSCode treats it as "Django HTML Template". January 2023

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `settings.json`

```
  "files.associations": {
    "*.html": "html",
  }
```